# HTML automatically highlight current day in Opening-Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please note we just started HTML and CSS, so sorry for basic questions.

We have to make a website for a school project about and by us chosen topic or thing. I've chosen my uncle's metalworking shop. I want to implement an table with the opening hours. I searched the web and found out I had to use JavaScript for this, which I never used. I tried something, but it's not working.

It should get the current day and then get the `<tr>` by the weekday ID and add an CSS class for further formatting.

```
<i>

    function weekday() {
        var d = new Date();
        
        if (d.getDay() = 0)     {
                            document.getElementById("Sunday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                            }
        
        if (d.getDay() = 1)     {
                            document.getElementById("Monday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                            }
        
        if (d.getDay() = 2)     {
                            document.getElementById("Tuesday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                            }
        
        if (d.getDay() = 3)     {
                            document.getElementById("Wednesday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                            }
        
        if (d.getDay() = 4)     {
                            document.getElementById("Thursday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                            }
        
        if (d.getDay() = 5)     {
                            document.getElementById("Friday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                            }
        
        if (d.getDay() = 6)     {
                            document.getElementById("Saturday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                            }                   
                        }

</i>
```

I think I could have done this with CASE Of, but as I said, I never used Javascript

Comment: When programming try and align things in terms of naming so a variable or value can cascade through without any logic required. If you named your element `#day_4` this would be trivial, but instead you're having to convert between numbers and English names, way messier.

Comment: Reminder: `=` is an **assignment operator** and `==` is for comparisons. This code probably produces a whole heap of errors. When working on browser JavaScript code, *always* have your JavaScript error console open.

Comment: Have you covered `switch`? Though I would rather create an array for days of week and use `d` as an index to retrieve the string.  `document.getElementById(daysOfWeek[d])`.

Comment: Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/hcxnpk5r/

Comment: If you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) it makes stuff like this a lot less messy. `document.getElementById('x').classList.add('y')` becomes `$('#x').addClass('y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.OpeningDay { background-color: yellow; }

<div id="Sunday">
Sunday
</div>
<div id="Monday">
Monday
</div>
<div id="Tuesday">
Tuesday
</div>
<div id="Wednesday">
Wednesday
</div>
<div id="Thursday">
Thursday
</div>
<div id="Friday">
Friday
</div>
<div id="Saturday">
Saturday
</div>

weekday();

function weekday() {
    var d = new Date();

    if (d.getDay() == 0)     {
                        document.getElementById("Sunday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                        }

    if (d.getDay() == 1)     {
                        document.getElementById("Monday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                        }

    if (d.getDay() == 2)     {
                        document.getElementById("Tuesday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                        }

    if (d.getDay() == 3)     {
                        document.getElementById("Wednesday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                        }

    if (d.getDay() == 4)     {
                        document.getElementById("Thursday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                        }

    if (d.getDay() == 5)     {
                        document.getElementById("Friday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                        }

    if (d.getDay() == 6)     {
                        document.getElementById("Saturday").classList.add('OpeningDay');
                        }                   
                    }
```

The fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hcxnpk5r/

Answer (score 2):

even simple!

```js
weekday();

function weekday() {
  var d = new Date().getDay();
  document.getElementById("day-"+d).classList.add('opening-day');    
}
```

```css
.opening-day { 
  background-color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div id="day-0">
  Sunday
</div>
<div id="day-1">
  Monday
</div>
<div id="day-2">
  Tuesday
</div>
<div id="day-3">
  Wednesday
</div>
<div id="day-4">
  Thursday
</div>
<div id="day-5">
  Friday
</div>
<div id="day-6">
  Saturday
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If condition should be Boolean like d.getDay() == 0. What you are doing is an assignment.